# How can I pass data from email to the app while launching an app from email?

Tags: android, flutter

Can you suggest to me the ways to launch an app from email? More importantly, how can I pass "meeting invitation" that was attached in email, to the app while launching it. The app I am developing needs this data such as meeting invitation details in order to plan something out. Can you suggest me the ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an intent filter in your manifest

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

    <data
        android:host="www.example.com"
        android:path="/launch"
        android:scheme="http"/>
</intent-filter>
```

For the email link set as http://www.example.com/launch.
Then, links to http://www.example.com/launch will bring up your app (in a chooser, along with the Web browse) on devices that have your app, and will bring up your Web page on devices that do not have your app.